# Improving Javascript Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm trying to improve the following code (for a button counter), but I'm unsure on initial inspection.

```
document.querySelectorAll("#minus")[0].addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  document.querySelectorAll("#number")[0].innerText = Number(document.querySelectorAll("#number")[0].innerText) - 1
})

document.querySelectorAll("#plus")[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  document.querySelectorAll("#number")[0].innerText = Number(document.querySelectorAll("#number")[0].innerText) + 1
})
```

How would I make this code more efficient?

I'm also looking to add a rule where the counter cannot reach zero.

Thankyou kindly for any help :)

Comment: A good way to remember the difference between Java and Javascript is that Javascript has "script" at the end.

Comment: While this code could be improved, it won’t show any performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten it by using `querySelector`, and add a condition like below:

```js
var num = document.querySelector("#number")
, plus = document.querySelector("#plus")
, minus = document.querySelector("#minus")

minus.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var value = Number(num.innerText)
  num.innerText = value === 1 ? 1 : value - 1
})

plus.addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
  num.innerText = Number(num.innerText) + 1
})
```

```css
div{ text-align: center; cursor: pointer; width: 100px; outline: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<div id="plus">+</div>
<div id="minus">-</div>
<div id="number">1</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou Anurag - extremely helpful.

How do I stop it reaching 0? Currently, it will allow to go to 0.